# PHP passwd error

Tags: php, shellexecute, shell-exec, passwd

I'm doing this:

```
$user = 'kevin';
$pass = 'nivek';
shell_exec('echo -e "' . $pass . '\n' . $pass . '" | sudo passwd ' . $user);`
```

But when I execute this, I get this error:

```
Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: Sorry, passwords do not match
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

Why? How can I solve this and how can I hide the output from passwd?

Comment: Does the command work in console?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/change-linux-or-unix-system-password-using-php-script.html

Comment: No, --stdin gives an error here.

Comment: Thanks, Wh1T3h4Ck5 (what a name ;p). It's working!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
$user = 'kevin';
$pass = 'nivek';
shell_exec('echo -e "' . $pass . '" | sudo passwd --stdin ' . $user);
```

That appears to work for me (although tested without sudo, you may need the second).

I'm not sure that sudo would even work.

Comment: Sorry, wrong comment. Got this error: `passwd: unrecognized option '--stdin'`

Comment: What distro are you using? This works fine on Red Hat (and derivatives) at least.

Answer (score 2):

Use --stdin for passwd to read from standard input. Then you can pipe the password.